# javaのScannerクラスでString入力を実装した場合、abcなどの英数字はコマンドプロンプト上で入出力できますが、日本語では入力はできても出力されません。

Tags: java, windows

#### 実現したいこと

・String型でScannerクラスを使い、日本語を出力したい

・コマンドプロンプトに、「こんにちは〇〇(日本語)さん」と出力したい

```
import java.util.Scanner ;

class HelloNext{

public static void main(String[] args) {
String x ;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in) ;

System.out.print("名前を入力してください。 > ") ;
x = sc.nextLine() ;

System.out.println() ;
System.out.println("こんにちは" + x + "さん。") ;

}

}
```

というプログラムを作成しました。
これをWindows上のWindows PowerShellで実行した所、

```
1)名前を入力してください。 > abc

こんにちはabcさん。

2)名前を入力してください。 > あいうえお

こんにちはさん。

3)名前を入力してください。 > あbう

こんにちはbさん。
```

となり、日本語入力した場合、名前として認識されず出力が「こんにちはさん。」と出力が失敗してしまいます。

Ubuntu上の端末では問題なく出力された為、恐らく環境の問題だと思われます。

解決策をご教授して頂ければ幸いです。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

・JDK : 20.0.1
・Eclipse　で書きました。

Comment: UbuntuとWindowsの違いには詳しくないのですが、Windowsのコマンドプロンプトとは具体的に何か(cmd.exeかPowerShellか）、コンパイルを行ったのはUbuntu上かWindows上か、具体的なコマンド(`java HelloNext`など）を書くと解答しやすくなるかもしれません。

Comment: @lamrongol に同じようなことを指摘したときは無視されましたけど。端末の種類が本当にコマンドプロンプトなのか、端末自体の設定は何か、chcpの設定は何か、起動したシェルは何か、記述すべきです。多分意図的に特殊なのを使ってます。

Comment: ちゃんと質問を編集しそうにないので一応書いておくと、javaはJDK18からシステムロケールを見ずにUTF-8が設定されます。なので、ScannerはUTF-8を仮定してStringに変換することになりますが、もしその際にUTF-8にないバイト並びで文字化けするのであれば、通常'?'になります。しかし今回の現象は消えているのでこれは出力時に消えていると判断する必要があります。

Answer (score 0):

> 実現したいこと
> ・String型でScannerクラスを使い、日本語を出力したい
> ・コマンドプロンプトに、「こんにちは〇〇(日本語)さん」と出力したい

標準入力(System.in)の文字コードを以下のとおり明示的に指定すればよいです。

```java
//Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in) ;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, "Shift-JIS") ;
```

実行するコマンドプロンプトの文字コードはデフォルトのままであることを前提としています。

```
C:\>chcp
現在のコード ページ: 932
```

---

Windowsのコマンドプロンプト(cmd)での入力はシフトJISのようです。
Windowsのシステムロケール）をUTF-8に変更してもよいのですが、影響が大きすぎるので現時点ではJavaのソースコードを変更する方がよいと思います。

---

ソースコードを修正せず、システムロケールもシフトＪＩＳのままで、
Windowsのcmdで日本語を表示させるには実行時にfile.encodingがシフトJISであることを明示する必要があります。明示しないと標準入力(シフトＪＩＳ)が文字化けします。

```
java -Dfile.encoding=Shift_JIS クラス名
```

※PowerShellで実行する場合はオプションを二重引用符で囲む必要がありました。

```
java java "-Dfile.encoding=Shift_JIS" クラス名
```

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。

上記の通りに実行した所、解決には至りませんでした。
昨日から様々いじり倒しているのですが、どうにもうまくいかないようです、、、。

また、新たに分かった事として、入力中に日本語と英数字の場合でキャレットの挙動が異なる箇所がございました為、共有させていただきます。
恐らくこの部分が、問題の箇所だと思われます。

1)　英数字の場合
(入力中) 　abc | 　→ (入力確定後) abc |

2)日本語の場合
(入力中) 　|あいう　→ (入力確定後) あいう|

というような感じで、キャレットの位置が日本語の入力中のみ、文字の左側の同じ位置で点滅し続けています。

Comment: 度重なる返信失礼いたします。

システムロケールにおいて、「UTF-8を利用」というチェックボックスを外したところ、上手く動作するようになりました。
（以前、キャレットの位置はおかしいのですが、、、）

お騒がせして申し訳ございませんでした。

Comment: とりあえずjavaでシフトJISを指定したいのなら、ms932かwindows-31jを指定しましょう。